# date_format() unexpected results with <= or <= in where clause

Tags: hive, hiveql

We are using a built in calendar table `dm_reference.dim_date` with a sequence of dates:

```
select * from dm_reference.dim_date limit 10;
calendar_date  date_name, day_of_week
1999-01-01  January 1, 1999 1   5   Friday
1999-01-02  January 2, 1999 2   6   Saturday
1999-01-03  January 3, 1999 3   7   Sunday
1999-01-04  January 4, 1999 4   1   Monday
1999-01-05  January 5, 1999 5   2   Tuesday
1999-01-06  January 6, 1999 6   3   Wednesday
1999-01-07  January 7, 1999 7   4   Thursday
1999-01-08  January 8, 1999 8   5   Friday
1999-01-09  January 9, 1999 9   6   Saturday
1999-01-10  January 10, 1999    10  7   Sunday
```

I wanted to filter this to only include dates between August 2014 and the current year month.

If I `select min(date_format(calendar_date, "YYYYMM")) from dm_reference.dim_date` I get returned `199901`

So, I tried the following query to format my calendar_date field as year and month and then to filter to include dates between august 14 now:

```
select 
  distinct date_format(calendar_date, "YYYY-MMM") as year_month
  ,  date_format(calendar_date, "YYYYMM") as year_month_num -- for ordering in asc
from dm_reference.dim_date
  where date_format(calendar_date, "YYYYMM") <= 201408
    and  date_format(calendar_date, "YYYYMM") <= date_format(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp()), "YYYYMM")    
    order by year_month_num;
```

This returns dates going all the way back to 1999 whereas I expected the earliest date in this query result to be august 2014.

Any idea why this is happening? How can I query our calendar to only include a filtered date range?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are complicating the query. You can simply filter for the required date range using

```
select * 
from dm_reference.dim_date
where calendar_date >= '2014-08-01' and calendar_date < trunc(current_date,'MM')
```

This outputs all dates on or after August 2014 until the end of last month. If you need data until today, use the ending condition as `calendar_date <= current_date`.

The reason your query doesn't return expected results is because the condition is `year month of calendar_date <= '201408' and year month of calendar_date <= '201808'`, which is everything before `201408`.

Comment: Thanks that works except I noticed that when I just used ```<= current_date``` the results go to December of this year as opposed to August. Any idea why that is?